# Can one benefit from the Sechach through Hataras Nedarim

Tags: halacha, korban, sukkah, nedarim-shevuot

The Gemara (Sukkah 9a) learns out from the verse, that just like it is forbidden to benefit from a sacrifice, so too is it forbidden to benefit from the sukkah

The question is: is it possible to benefit from the Sukkah through Hataras Nedarim like it would be regarding an animal that was consecrated to be a sacrifice?

Comment: What vow would you be annulling in this case?

Comment: Wouldn't that mean it's not a sukkah anymore and you didn't fulfill the mitzvah?

Comment: @Heshy, a sukkah is Kosher even if it wasn’t made for the Mitzvah

Comment: Is the schach of sukot ganbach or rakbash permitted to benefit from? Leaving aside that I don't think the gemara is necessarily comparing the schach to a live hekdesh animal for all purposes, it seems one who did this would be trying to have his cake and eat it too by leaving it as schach but without the din that comes with schach. Relatedly, the gemara doesn't mention that you can designate schach al tanai like you can with noi sukkah.

Comment: @Heshy, or let’s say a bit of Sechach fell from the Sukkah

Comment: The schach fell down sounds like a better example. Or maybe you built a sukkah but decided you want to use another one instead?

Comment: @DoubleAA, my question is if the  intention of designating the Sechach for the Mitzvah count as a vow like by a Korban

Comment: Are you talking about before he used it for the mitzvah or after?